# Adding Additional Fields to CDP (Data Cloud) Data Stream

Tags: datacloud, salesforce-cdp, cdp

I'm new to Salesforce Data Cloud (CDP) so these questions are kind of basic. I lost access to my trial instance so wasn't able to try and also haven't found any documentation on these questions specifically. Here are my questions:

1. Can fields/formulas be added to an existing data stream **hasn't** been ingested?
2. Can fields/formulas be added to an existing data stream **has** been ingested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_add_new_source_fields.htm&type=5), you can add Source Fields after the Data Stream has been created or add Formula Fields as per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_add_action.htm&type=5)

The key restriction to fields in Data Streams is that the data type can't be changed after the field has been added.